# Download SQL SERVER AGENT - Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have downloaded SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO but SQL SERVER AGENT is not found.

Should I install it separately?

Can anybody tell me the link where SQL SERVER AGENT is available as a Freeware to download it?

Comment: If you are using SQL Express it is not part of the package. Your best bet is to use something like http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx as an alternative or use the Windows Scheduler to run scripts into the database engine.

Answer (score 6):

The agent is not visible if you use SQL Server Management Studio Express to connect to an SQL Server. You need to install the client tools that come with the server setup to get SQL Server Management Studio.

If you are using SQL Server Express, it has no agent.

Comment: Ok then how to install those client tools?

Comment: This should help you: http://mundeep.wordpress.com/2007/11/23/installing-sql-server-2005-management-studio/

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server Agent is a service of SQL Server, **not** SQL Server Management Studio (which is, in and of itself, an administration tool).

Since SQL Server Agent is part of SQL Server, it's not free. You can learn about creating a job in SQL Server Agent [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx).

What, pray tell, are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Ok thanks for your prompt reply.

I want to create job. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You (or your company) will need to purchase the full version of SQL server in order to use this functionality.

The other option is to find the command-line instruction that will achieve what you want and then use Windows Task Scheduler to run the command on the schedule you want.