# Scheduled import from SQL Server to mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, import

Is it possible to setup a scheduled(preferably hourly) import of data from SQL Server to mySQL?

Manual import of data is working through ODBC using dbForge Studio for mySQL (604942 rows imported).

Due to the large volume of data, i would not prefer triggering the import command every now and then manually, but rather automatically update the most recent updated rows only. I have a field called [Last_Modified_Date].

The intention is to update rows with this condition:

[Last_Modified_Date] >= last 1 hour

I am a complete beginner in Databases. I only survived til date by searching solutions online.

Comment: i found a workaround for this.

i used SQLyog to schedule the queries for me. It saves the query in an XML file and schedules it using Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/need-to-migrate-sql-server-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL Agent to schedule a job.

In the query that is selecting the records to move, you could use add your filter on [Last_Modified_Date] to align with the schedule of the SQL Agent Job.

Comment: Im currently using SQL Server Management Studio Express. I've read that SQL Agent only comes with the paid version. Any alternatives? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096229/download-sql-server-agent-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: What version of MS SQL? What version of Windows? What version of MySQL?